# Prove that if $X$ and $X^{\prime}$ are homeomorphic then so are $T X$ and $T X^{\prime}$. ($TX$ denotes cone over $X$).

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ the subset of $X \times[0,1]$ given by $X \times\{1\}$. The space $X \times[0,1] / A$ is called the cone over $X$. Denote this space by $T X$. Prove that if $X$ and $X^{\prime}$ are homeomorphic then so are $T X$ and $T X^{\prime}$.

I think there is an issue with the following proof (which I only sketch here):

Proof: Let $g: X \times[0,1] \to X' \times[0,1]$ be the homeomorphism based on homeomorphism between $X$ and $X'$.  Let $f_X$ be the corresponding quotient map for the space $TX$.  Then $ \phi := f_{X'} \circ g \circ f_X^{-1} $ is a homeomorphism.

The issue I have is that $\phi$ may not be invertible/bijective, as the quotient map $f_X$ may not be injective/invertible.  So I'm asking if anyone get fill in the details of this attempt or provide other solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Your idea makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go the other way: suppose $h: X \to X'$ is a homeomorphism.

Then show that $H: TX \to TX'$ defined by $H([(x,t)]) = [(h(x), t)]$ is well-defined and a homeomorphism too. Here $[(x,t)]$ denotes the equivalence class of $(x,t)$ in $X \times [0,1]$ so a point of $TX$ (resp. $X' \times [0,1]$ and $TX'$).

It's a simple check of the definitions.

Comment: How to show that $O$ is open in $TX$ if and only if $H(O)$ is open in $TX'$?  I can only get at openness via the preimage under the quotient map so I'm getting something similar as to what is suggested in the 'proof' above.

Comment: @helios321 $H$ is continuous as $q\circ H= (h  \times 1) \circ q$ for $q$ the appropriate quotient maps. For the inverse of $H$ we have similar equations.

Comment: What does  $h \times 1$ signify?

Comment: @helios321 the Cartesian product map of $h$ and the relevant identity map.

Comment: How does this $q\circ H= (h  \times 1) \circ q$ show continuity of $H$ exactly?

Comment: @helios321 universal property of quotients. Look it up..